# How to fix UICollectionView - All cells disappear - Xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout, uiview-hierarchy

I am using a UICollectionView in C# Xamarin ios and sometimes all of the cells will disappear from the screen. This happens normally on a scroll and I have to re-invoke the view that my UICollection View is on.
I can't show my exact code as this is a project that I am working on but the initialization basics look a little like this:

```
Bounds screenBounds = screen.Bounds 

UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();

UICollectionView collectionView = new UICollectionView(layout, bounds)
```

I initialize a few other things like source and register cell and also add separation and border styles.

I have been also getting an error about a view not being in the hierarchy don't know if this has anything to do with it.

I do return the collectionView at the end and will add this returned value to my template which has a scroll view in which I add the UICollectionView to.
May I also mention I don't use any of the StoryBoard and am using a DuqueReusable cell in my collection view source.

I have been stuck on this for ages so thank you in advance for anyone who can give me any sort of tips or answers to this question.

Comment: Hi ,welcome to SO ! I think you need to share more sample code here and explain the disappear phenomenon beter with screenshot here .By the way , if you modify content of CollectionView , need to `collectionView.ReloadData();` . Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534202/how-to-implement-uicollectionview-xamarin-ios/59538894#59538894) to implement CollectionView without storyboard in Xamarin.iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Insure you make any changes to ItemsSource or to cells data on UI thread only, otherwise you might obtains an uncatchanble async crash and you'll end up with an empty view.

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
         // do your stuff

    });
```